# Updating TeamViewer

Tags: centos, yum, teamviewer

I installed TeamViewer (v10) on CentOS 7.

When I connect to that box, I get a message that the remote software is out of date and that I should click on the label to update the software remotely. That action, however does nothing.

I opened a terminal window and went to root and typed in:

```
[root@] # yum update teamviewer
```

The response came back as "No packages marked for update".

I typed in

```
# yum update
```

The response was "no packages marked for update." I do see teamviewer if I do

```
# yum -qa | grep teamviewer
teamviewer-10.0.46203-0.i686
```

TeamViewer on CentOS 7 does not have the typical `Help | check for updates`.

Is there an easy way to update TeamViewer or do I need to uninstall, download, and then reinstall?

Comment: I don't use centos so I don't know what is triggering that remote software message. Are there any more details around that?

Comment: I have TeamViewer running on my local Windows desktop, which is up to date. The software auto updates/notifies me (cool feature). When I connect to my Linux (CentOS) box, I am able to connect, no issues, just I get the message that I am running an outdated version on the remote. As I have not updated the software for some time and TeamViewer updated my Windows client, the message is probably accurate. I was just wondering if it is possible to streamline the update process besides the uninstall/download/install with possible reboots through in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App developers don't always update their windows and linux versions at the same time. In fact, they often don't. For Windows software that happens to grudgingly have a Linux version, the Linux version is often neglected. and vice-versa.

In other words, maybe there is no updated version of teamviewer for linux. Maybe there will be one in future.

According to https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx version 10.0.46203 is the latest version available for Centos.

There's a newer beta version (11.0.50678 beta) there available for Debian.  Maybe when that becomes the new release version, it'll be made available for Centos too.